# Inserir elementos na coluna da esquerda, em Bootstrap, sem afectar a altura das linhas da coluna da direita?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Como é que ao inserir elementos na coluna da esquerda isso não afecta a altura das linhas da coluna da direita; ou seja, como faço duas colunas totalmente independentes para que ao inserir elementos numa coluna isso não afecte em nada a outra?

Se eu inserir uma imagem na coluna da esquerda (neste caso o logo_blank.png), a imagem da bicicleta (product1), que está na coluna da direita, move-se para baixo. Ora, como fazer para que a bicicleta não se mova ela tem de ficar onde está?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="./css/lotti.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<title>Tombola Dinamica</title>

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link href="./b_styles/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
  <style type="text/css">
     img { behavior: url("pngfix.htc"); }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
   </head>
<body scroll="no" style="overflow: auto">
<header class="image-background">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row mx-md-n5">
               <div class="col-md-7">

<img id="logo" src="./img/outras/logo_blank.png" class="rounded float-left logo" alt="...">   
           
 <img id="logo" src="./img/outras/logo_blank.png" class="rounded float-left logo" alt="...">                   
                   
               </div>
           <div class="col-md-5">

        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row mt-3">
           <div class="col-md-7">
 

           </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
   <img id="apostSort" src="./img/outras/product1.jpg" class="rounded float-left" alt="...">
  </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row mt-4">
           <div class="col-md-7">


           </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
           <div id="d4w4" >
               
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row mt-4">
           <div class="col-md-7">
 

           </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 ">
           <div id="d4w3"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row mt-1">
           <div class="col-md-7">

                      
           </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
           <div id="d4w2"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tem algum código? Sem informação suficiente não da pra tentar ajudar.

Comment: Cara de mais detalhes... Não afete a altura da coluna do lado em que sentido? Coloque qual versão do Bootstrap está com problema, se possível coloque uma imagem do layout e o que vc já tiver de código...

Comment: Publiquei então o código. Se inserir uma imagem na coluna da esquerda a imagem da bicicleta que está na coluna da direita move-se para baixo. Ora, como fazer para que a bicicleta não se mova?

Comment: @user1856464 Se você tem outra dúvida (mesmo que relacionada a esta da publicação) faça uma nova pergunta com seu código atualizado e o novo problema.

Comment: Com a explicação do hugocsl já entendi melhor o problema. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o problema é que vc talvez não tenha pegado muto bem como funciona o Grid do Bootstrap. Cada `div` com class `row` representa uma linha, ou seja, vc nunca vai ter uma `row` ao lado da outra, sempre vai ser um `row` abaixo da outra, em coluna. Já dentro da `row` todos os elementos se alinha na horizontal, um ao lado do outro, até que a linha quebre o algum elemento pule para o espaço de baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seu problema é que vc tem uma `row` com uma imagem dentro e do lado uma `div` vazia, ela que cria esse "espaço vazio" e esta quebrando seu layout. Para arrumar basta vc colocar a imagem que está na `row` de baixo nessa `div` vazia. Assim todos ficam na mesma `row`.

Olha ai como ficaria. **Execute em *"página toda"* para ver melhor**.

**OBS:** Se vc quiser um espaço entre a imagem e o topo adicione um `margint-top: 100px` por exemplo na imagem. Eu inclusive já coloquei ai a classe nativa `mt-5` do Bootstrap que é equivale a `5re`m de altura, mas vc pode criar um css com o `margin-top` que quiser e colocar na imagem...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="./css/lotti.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <title>Tombola Dinamica</title>

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
    <link href="http://clubesorte.org/b_styles/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
  <style type="text/css">
     img { behavior: url("pngfix.htc"); }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
  <style>
  
  </style>
</head>

<body scroll="no" style="overflow: auto">
    <header class="image-background">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row mx-md-n5">
                <div class="col-md-7">

                    <img id="logo" src="https://www.clubesorte.org/e_tombolas/a_clubesorte/16n/teste_grid-bootstrap/img/outras/logo_blank.png"
                        class="rounded float-left logo" alt="...">

                    <img id="logo" src="https://www.clubesorte.org/e_tombolas/a_clubesorte/16n/teste_grid-bootstrap/img/outras/logo_blank.png"
                        class="rounded float-left logo" alt="...">
                    <img id="logo" src="https://www.clubesorte.org/e_tombolas/a_clubesorte/16n/teste_grid-bootstrap/img/outras/logo_blank.png"
                        class="rounded float-left logo" alt="...">
                    <img id="logo" src="https://www.clubesorte.org/e_tombolas/a_clubesorte/16n/teste_grid-bootstrap/img/outras/logo_blank.png"
                        class="rounded float-left logo" alt="...">
                    <img id="logo" src="https://www.clubesorte.org/e_tombolas/a_clubesorte/16n/teste_grid-bootstrap/img/outras/logo_blank.png"
                        class="rounded float-left logo" alt="...">
                    <img id="logo" src="https://www.clubesorte.org/e_tombolas/a_clubesorte/16n/teste_grid-bootstrap/img/outras/logo_blank.png"
                        class="rounded float-left logo" alt="...">
                    <img id="logo" src="https://www.clubesorte.org/e_tombolas/a_clubesorte/16n/teste_grid-bootstrap/img/outras/logo_blank.png"
                        class="rounded float-left logo" alt="...">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img id="apostSort" src="https://www.clubesorte.org/e_tombolas/a_clubesorte/16n/teste_grid-bootstrap/img/outras/product1.jpg"
                    class="rounded float-left mt-5" alt="...">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-md-7">


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-7">


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div id="d4w4">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-7">


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 ">
                    <div id="d4w3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-1">
                <div class="col-md-7">


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div id="d4w2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```